# Calculate $\sin^5\alpha-\cos^5\alpha$ if $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\frac12$

Tags: trigonometry

Calculate $$\sin^5\alpha-\cos^5\alpha$$ if $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\dfrac12$.

The main idea in problems like this is to write the expression that we need to calculate in terms of the given one (in this case we know $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\frac12$).

I don't see how to even start to work on the given expression as we cannot use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ or $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. So in other words, I can't figure out how to factor the expression (even a little).

> The given answer is $\dfrac{79}{128}$.

Comment: Hint: Yes, you can. Try thinking about $a^5 - b^5.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson, thank you for the response. That's what I've been doing this whole time thinking about the problem, but as a matter of fact, I don't think I can really factor $a^5-b^5$. If the factorization really is $(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)$, I have no clue how it is derived.

Comment: If you start with $a^n - 1$ and note that $1$ is a root of that polynomial, then you can factor this. Now set $n=5.$ The resulting factorization is a common pattern.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I am trying to see for myself why $1$ is a root of the polynomial $P(a)=a^n-1$. This means $P(1)=0$, right?

Comment: $P(1)=1^n-1 = 1-1 = 0.$

Comment: How is it derived? Multiply across the RHS and notice that almost everything will cancel out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Let $~\displaystyle x = \sin(\alpha), y = \cos(\alpha) = \implies 
(x - y) = \frac{1}{2}, ~\left(x^5 - y^5\right) = \color{red}{what?}$

**Tools**

- $T_1 ~: ~(x - y)^2 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2.$
- $T_2 ~: ~(x - y)^3 = x^3 - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 - y^3.$
- $T_3 ~: ~(x - y)^5 = x^5 - 5x^4y + 10x^3y^2 - 10x^2y^3 + 5xy^4 - y^5.$

**Plan of Attack** 
Since $~x^2 + y^2 = 1~,$ there **is** sufficient information to compute $(xy)$.  Using this you can compute $x^3 - y^3$, and using this you can compute $x^5 - y^5.$

---

From $T_1,$ you have that

$$\frac{1}{4} = 1 - 2xy \implies xy = \frac{3}{8}. \tag1 $$

---

Using (1), from $T_2,$ you have that

$$\frac{1}{8} = \left(x^3 - y^3\right) - 3xy(x-y) \implies $$

$$\frac{1}{8} = \left(x^3 - y^3\right) - 3\left(\frac{3}{8}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \implies (x^3 - y^3) = \frac{11}{16}. \tag2 $$

---

Using (1) and (2), from $T_3,$ you have that

$$\frac{1}{32} = \left(x^5 - y^5\right) -5(xy)(x^3 - y^3) + 10(xy)^2(x - y) \implies $$

$$\frac{1}{32} = \left(x^5 - y^5\right) - 5\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)\left(\frac{11}{16}\right) + 10\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \implies $$

$$\frac{4}{128} = \left(x^5 - y^5\right) - \frac{165}{128} + \frac{90}{128} \implies$$

$$\left(x^5 - y^5\right) = \frac{4 + 165 - 90}{128} = \frac{79}{128}.$$

Answer (score 3):

using the hint: $x^5-y^5 = (x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$

Let's create the parts:

since $x^2+y^2=1$ we have:
$(x^2+y^2)^2 = x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4 = 1$ (2)

We have a big part of it but we are missing $xy$ so

we know $x-y = 1/2$ squaring both side: $x^2 + y^2 -2xy = 1/4$ since $x^2+y^2=1$ then $xy=3/8$ (1).

using (2)

$(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - x^2y^2 + xy(x^2+y^2)) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \frac{9}{64} + \frac{3}{8}\times1) = \frac{79}{128}$

Comment: $x^3y+xy^3=xy(x^{\color{red}{2}}+y^{\color{red}{2}})=xy=\frac38.$ Use this instead of $\frac38\times\frac{14}8$ and you get the result claimed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
x^{5} - y^{5} & = (x - y)(x^{4} + x^{3}y + x^{2}y^{2} + xy^{3} + y^{4})\\\\
\end{align*}

Then you can rearrange the inner terms in order to fit the proposed information.

Answer (score 2):

I think we're all overthinking the problem a bit here!

Given that

$$\sin\alpha -\cos\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$$

set $x=\sin\alpha$ so that $\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and solve the quadratic for $x$. Your answer is now

$$\sin^5\alpha -\cos^5\alpha=x^5-(1-x)^\frac{5}{2}$$

Comment: Not how I would have immediately solved it. Well done!

Comment: Thanks. It helps if one is too lazy to want to do a polynomial expansion :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why can we assume that the cosine is positive?

Comment: You don't have to use the principal value. You could very well end up with 2 possible answers - I haven't actually worked through the quadratic.

Comment: Well the roots of the equation are $x_{1,2}=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{7}}{4}$. This to the power of $5$...

Comment: Yes, that's what I get too. And with the principal value (positive square root), it matches the answer in the spoiler.

Comment: From $\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you get one solution of $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\frac12$ and one solution of $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\frac12.$ From $\cos\alpha=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you get the other solution of $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\frac12$ and the other solution of $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\frac12.$ The solutions of $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha=\frac12$ correspond to points where the line $y=x+\frac12$ intersects the unit circle, symmetric across the line $y=-x,$ and whichever one you take, the value of $\sin^5\alpha-\cos^5\alpha$ will be the same.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. With $\cos\alpha=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$, you get two roots $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{7}}{4}$ and hence two distinct values of $\sin^5\alpha-\cos^5\alpha$, unless I'm missing something. Does taking the positive root for $\cos\alpha$ entail the obligation to consider only the positive root of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

We will use a few identities.

First is the Pythagorean Identity:
$$\sin^2\alpha +\cos^2\alpha = 1$$
Second is a simple factorization:
$$a^5 - b^5 = (a-b)(a^4 + a^3b + a^2b^2 + ab^3 + b^4) = (a-b)(a^4 + b^4 + ab(a^2+b^2+ab))$$

Third will help us write things of fourth degree in terms of second and first degree terms:
$$a^4 + b^4 = (a^2+b^2)^2-2(ab)^2$$

So we can combine them and get the following:
$$a^5 - b^5 = (a-b)((a^2+b^2)^2-2(ab)^2 + ab(a^2+ab+b^2))$$

Now, all we have to do is calculate $\sin\alpha \cos\alpha$ and plug the values in.

$$\sin\alpha - \cos\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$$
Squaring both sides, we get
$$\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha - 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 - 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \frac{3}{8}$$

Then, if we let $a = \sin\alpha$ and $b = \cos\alpha$, we get
$$\sin^5\alpha - \cos^5\alpha = (\sin\alpha - \cos\alpha)((\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha)^2 - 2(\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)^2 \\+ \sin\alpha\cos\alpha (\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha + \sin\alpha\cos\alpha))$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(1^2 - 2\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{8}\left(1+\frac{3}{8}\right)\right) = \frac{79}{128}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Solve $ \sin{z}-\cos{z}=\frac{1}{2}$

This results in $e^{iz}=\frac{\sqrt{7}-i}{2(i-1)}$

Plugging this into the complex sin and cos definition results in:
$\sin{z}=\frac{1-1\sqrt{7}}{4}$ and $\cos{z}= \frac{-1-1\sqrt{7}}{4}$
When applying this in $sin^5z-cos^5z$ all uneven powers of $\sqrt(7)$ cancel out.

What remains is: $sin^5z-cos^5z=\frac{1+70+5\cdot 49}{2^9}=\frac{79}{128}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}=\sin\left(\alpha-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\sin x$$ where $\alpha-\dfrac\pi4=x$

$$\sin^5\alpha-\cos^5\alpha=\sin^5\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)-\cos^5\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)=\dfrac{(\cos x+\sin x)^5-(\cos x-\sin x)^5}{(\sqrt2)^5}$$

Now,
$$(\cos x+\sin x)^5-(\cos x-\sin x)^5=2\sin^5x+2\binom53\sin^3x\cos^2x+2\binom54\sin x\cos^4x$$

Use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x=1-\left(\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\right)^2=?$